# How can I retrieve contact events synced from Google Contacts without a year?

Tags: android, contactscontract

I'm using the code below to retrieve a cursor for events and contacts and it's working just fine for events with a year specified. Unfortunately, events where only the day and month are set are not returned by this query.

I have set these dates in [Google Contacts](http://www.google.com/contacts) for some contact birthdays and I'm wondering if I need to use RawContacts rather than ContactsContract to get these values?

**Update**: It seems that events entered into the phone without a year are retrieved. It is only events added via http://www.google.com/contacts that are not retrieved. I can see these events in the Contacts app though - displayed as something like `--05-23`.

```
String[] projection = new String[] {
    ContactsContract.Contacts._ID,
    ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME,
    Event.CONTACT_ID,
    Event.START_DATE,
    Event.TYPE
};

Cursor c = mContext.getContentResolver().query(
    ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI,
    projection,
    ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + "= ?",
    new String[] { Event.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE },
    Event.START_DATE);
c.moveToFirst();

int nameIndex = c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME);
int dateIndex = c.getColumnIndex(Event.START_DATE);

String name, date;
while (c.moveToNext()) {
    name = c.getString(nameIndex);
    date = c.getString(dateIndex);
    Log.d(TAG, "Event for " + name + " is " + date);
}

c.close();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm running on the Nexus S (2.3.4) and I have used your exact code and I get all contacts printed out including ones with no year.

```
07-19 17:08:36.847: DEBUG/test(24646): Event for Warren Upton is --12-01
07-19 17:08:36.851: DEBUG/test(24646): Event for Marion Atkins is 1934-11-24
```

Can you give any more details on how to reproduce the problem?

Comment: Hi Jeff, thanks for looking into this. The problem actually seems to be just with contacts edited online at http://www.google.com/contacts

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing events with no year don't have `Event.START_DATE` set (since by definition a date would be day/month/year). If you remove it from the projection and sort do they get retrieved?

Comment: No, I'm afraid they are still not returned.